# trouble with creating JTable to display data

Tags: java, swing, jtable, layout-manager

I am doing this payroll project for school.
The idea is for the user to input the employee's name, work hour, hourly rate, and select department from the ComboBox.
There will display 3 buttons, "Add More", "Display Result", and "exit".
"Add More" button will store the input into several arryalist and set the textfield to blank to allow more input.
"Display Result" will generate a JTable at the bottom JPanel to display the employee's name, department, and weekly salary.

I am running into the problem of nothing shows up after hitting the "Display Result" button. Maybe I have misunderstand the purpose of the button event, but I am really confused right now. Please help!

Here is a [photobucket](http://s443.photobucket.com/user/bigwhiteegg/media/grfha425564_zpselymr3yp.jpg.html][IMG]http://i443.photobucket.com/albums/qq159/bigwhiteegg/grfha425564_zpselymr3yp.jpg) directURL PrtSc of the UI, hope it helps.

```
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.*;

public class PayrollFrame extends JFrame
{
    private JLabel nameMessageLabel, hourMessageLabel, rateMessageLabel, boxMessageLabel;
    private JTextField nameTextField, hourTextField, rateTextField;
    private JPanel inputPanel, buttonPanel, outputPanel, inputPanel1, inputPanel2, inputPanel3, inputPanel4;
    private JComboBox<String> departmentBox;
    private JButton addButton, displayButton, exitButton;
    private JTable resultTable;
    private String[] columnNames = {"Employee name", "Department", "Weekly Salary"};
    private Object[][] data;
    private int WINDOW_WIDTH = 400;
    private int WINDOW_HEIGHT = 500;

    ArrayList<String> name = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> hour = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> rate = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> department = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> salary = new ArrayList<String>();

    private String[] departments = {"IT", "Marketing", "Human Resource", "Sales", "Customer Service", "Financial"};

    /*default constructor*/
    public PayrollFrame()
    {
        super("Payroll");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT);
        setLayout(new GridLayout(3,1));
        buildInputPanel();
        buildButtonPanel();
        buildOutputPanel();

        add(inputPanel);
        add(buttonPanel);
        add(outputPanel);

        setVisible(true);
    }

    private void buildInputPanel()
    {
        nameMessageLabel = new JLabel("Employee Name: ");
        hourMessageLabel = new JLabel("Work Hour: ");
        rateMessageLabel = new JLabel("Hourly Rate: ");
        boxMessageLabel = new JLabel("Department: ");
        nameTextField = new JTextField(10);
        hourTextField = new JTextField(10);
        rateTextField = new JTextField(10);
        departmentBox = new JComboBox<String>(departments);

        inputPanel = new JPanel();
        inputPanel1 = new JPanel();
        inputPanel2 = new JPanel();
        inputPanel3 = new JPanel();
        inputPanel4 = new JPanel();

        inputPanel1.add(nameMessageLabel);
        inputPanel1.add(nameTextField);
        inputPanel2.add(hourMessageLabel);
        inputPanel2.add(hourTextField);
        inputPanel3.add(rateMessageLabel);
        inputPanel3.add(rateTextField);
        inputPanel4.add(boxMessageLabel);
        inputPanel4.add(departmentBox);

        inputPanel.add(inputPanel1);
        inputPanel.add(inputPanel2);
        inputPanel.add(inputPanel3);
        inputPanel.add(inputPanel4);
    }

    private void buildButtonPanel() 
    {
        addButton = new JButton("Add More");
        addButton.addActionListener(new ButtonAction());
        displayButton = new JButton("Display Result");
        displayButton.addActionListener(new ButtonAction());
        exitButton = new JButton("Exit");
        exitButton.addActionListener(new ButtonAction());

        buttonPanel = new JPanel();

        buttonPanel.add(addButton);
        buttonPanel.add(displayButton);
        buttonPanel.add(exitButton);
    }

    private void buildOutputPanel()
    {
        outputPanel = new JPanel();
    }

    /*Copy ArrayList into 2D array to display in JTable format*/
    private void printData() 
    {
        for(int i=0; i<name.size(); i++)
        {
            data[i][0]=name.get(i);
            data[i][2]=department.get(i);
            data[i][2]=salary.get(i);
        }
        resultTable = new JTable(data, columnNames);
        outputPanel = new JPanel();
        outputPanel.add(resultTable);
    }

    /*Function of 3 buttons*/
    private class ButtonAction implements ActionListener
    {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
        {
            if(e.getActionCommand()=="Add More")
            {
                name.add(nameTextField.getText());
                hour.add(hourTextField.getText());
                rate.add(rateTextField.getText());
                department.add((String) departmentBox.getSelectedItem());
                calculateSalary(hourTextField.getText(), rateTextField.getText());
                nameTextField.setText("");
                hourTextField.setText("");
                rateTextField.setText("");
            }
            else if(e.getActionCommand()=="Display Result")
            {

                printData();

            }
            else if(e.getActionCommand()=="Exit")
            {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        }

        /*Calculate the weekly salary*/
        private void calculateSalary(String hourString, String rateString) 
        {
            int tempHour = Integer.parseInt(hourString);
            double tempRate = Double.parseDouble(rateString);
            if(tempHour<=40)
            {
                salary.add(Double.toString(tempHour * tempRate));
            }
            else
            {
                salary.add(Double.toString(40 * tempRate + (tempHour - 40) * (tempRate * 1.5))); //all hour after 40 will pay 1.5
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! That looks like more code than strictly needed. Can you reduce the code further until no code can be removed while still running into the problem?

Comment: Yes, sorry about that. I'll be more careful next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start with...

```
if (e.getActionCommand() == "Add More") {
```

Is not how you compare `String`s in Java, you need to use the `equals` method instead, something like...

```
if ("Add More".equals(e.getActionCommand())) {
```

for example

<strike>Next you do...</strike>

```
add(inputPanel);
add(buttonPanel);
add(outputPanel);
```

which, when using a `BorderLayout`, adds each of the components to the default position within the `BorderLayout`, you need to provide position constraints for each component, otherwise strange things begin to happen, for example...

```
add(inputPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
add(outputPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
```

*I just realised that you're using a `GridLayout`, personally, I think you'll get a better result from `BorderLayout`, but that's me*

And then you create a new instance of `resultTable` and `outputPanel`, but you never add `outputPanel` to anything...

```
/*Copy ArrayList into 2D array to display in JTable format*/
private void printData() 
{
    for(int i=0; i<name.size(); i++)
    {
        data[i][0]=name.get(i);
        data[i][1]=department.get(i);
        data[i][2]=salary.get(i);
    }
    resultTable = new JTable(data, columnNames);
    outputPanel = new JPanel();
    outputPanel.add(resultTable);
}
```

A better idea would be to create `resultTable`, wrap in a `JScrollPane` and add it to your screen.

When you want to "print" the data, create a new `TableModel` and apply it to the `JTable`

For example...

```
private void buildOutputPanel() {
    outputPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    resultTable = new JTable();
    outputPanel.add(new JScrollPane(resultTable));
}

/*Copy ArrayList into 2D array to display in JTable format*/
private void printData() {
    for (int i = 0; i < name.size(); i++) {
        data[i][0] = name.get(i);
        data[i][2] = department.get(i);
        data[i][2] = salary.get(i);
    }
    DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames);
    resultTable.setModel(model);
}
```

Take a look at [How to Use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) and [How to Use Scroll Panes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html) for more details

**Example**

[image: Data]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableModel;

public class PayrollFrame extends JFrame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                PayrollFrame frame = new PayrollFrame();
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    private JLabel nameMessageLabel, hourMessageLabel, rateMessageLabel, boxMessageLabel;
    private JTextField nameTextField, hourTextField, rateTextField;
    private JPanel inputPanel, buttonPanel, outputPanel, inputPanel1, inputPanel2, inputPanel3, inputPanel4;
    private JComboBox<String> departmentBox;
    private JButton addButton, displayButton, exitButton;
    private JTable resultTable;
    private String[] columnNames = {"Employee name", "Department", "Weekly Salary"};
    private Object[][] data;
    private int WINDOW_WIDTH = 400;
    private int WINDOW_HEIGHT = 500;

    ArrayList<String> name = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> hour = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> rate = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> department = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> salary = new ArrayList<String>();

    private String[] departments = {"IT", "Marketing", "Human Resource", "Sales", "Customer Service", "Financial"};

    /*default constructor*/
    public PayrollFrame() {
        super("Payroll");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        buildInputPanel();
        buildButtonPanel();
        buildOutputPanel();

        add(inputPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        add(buttonPanel);
        add(outputPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        setVisible(true);
    }

    private void buildInputPanel() {
        nameMessageLabel = new JLabel("Employee Name: ");
        hourMessageLabel = new JLabel("Work Hour: ");
        rateMessageLabel = new JLabel("Hourly Rate: ");
        boxMessageLabel = new JLabel("Department: ");
        nameTextField = new JTextField(10);
        hourTextField = new JTextField(10);
        rateTextField = new JTextField(10);
        departmentBox = new JComboBox<String>(departments);

        inputPanel = new JPanel();
        inputPanel1 = new JPanel();
        inputPanel2 = new JPanel();
        inputPanel3 = new JPanel();
        inputPanel4 = new JPanel();

        inputPanel1.add(nameMessageLabel);
        inputPanel1.add(nameTextField);
        inputPanel2.add(hourMessageLabel);
        inputPanel2.add(hourTextField);
        inputPanel3.add(rateMessageLabel);
        inputPanel3.add(rateTextField);
        inputPanel4.add(boxMessageLabel);
        inputPanel4.add(departmentBox);

        inputPanel.add(inputPanel1);
        inputPanel.add(inputPanel2);
        inputPanel.add(inputPanel3);
        inputPanel.add(inputPanel4);
    }

    private void buildButtonPanel() {
        addButton = new JButton("Add More");
        addButton.addActionListener(new ButtonAction());
        displayButton = new JButton("Display Result");
        displayButton.addActionListener(new ButtonAction());
        exitButton = new JButton("Exit");
        exitButton.addActionListener(new ButtonAction());

        buttonPanel = new JPanel();

        buttonPanel.add(addButton);
        buttonPanel.add(displayButton);
        buttonPanel.add(exitButton);
    }

    private void buildOutputPanel() {
        outputPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        resultTable = new JTable();
        outputPanel.add(new JScrollPane(resultTable));      
    }

    /*Copy ArrayList into 2D array to display in JTable format*/
    private void printData() {
        for (int i = 0; i < name.size(); i++) {
            data[i][0] = name.get(i);
            data[i][2] = department.get(i);
            data[i][2] = salary.get(i);
        }
        TableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames);
        resultTable.setModel(model);
    }

    /*Function of 3 buttons*/
    private class ButtonAction implements ActionListener {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if ("Add More".equals(e.getActionCommand())) {
                name.add(nameTextField.getText());
                hour.add(hourTextField.getText());
                rate.add(rateTextField.getText());
                department.add((String) departmentBox.getSelectedItem());
                calculateSalary(hourTextField.getText(), rateTextField.getText());
                nameTextField.setText("");
                hourTextField.setText("");
                rateTextField.setText("");
            } else if ("Display Result".equals(e.getActionCommand())) {

                printData();

            } else if ("Exit".equals(e.getActionCommand())) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        }

        /*Calculate the weekly salary*/
        private void calculateSalary(String hourString, String rateString) {
            int tempHour = Integer.parseInt(hourString);
            double tempRate = Double.parseDouble(rateString);
            if (tempHour <= 40) {
                salary.add(Double.toString(tempHour * tempRate));
            } else {
                salary.add(Double.toString(40 * tempRate + (tempHour - 40) * (tempRate * 1.5))); //all hour after 40 will pay 1.5
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh~~ now I do remember the equal part. I'll start reading the oracle page now. Thanks for your help. :)

Comment: I do have one question, is the way I define the "Display Result" button correct? When it is onClick, the printData method will triggered to build a JTable, but what is next? How do I know if the outputPanel will display the table??

Comment: You kind of don't.  You trust that `outputPanel` and the `resultTable` have already been constructed and added to the UI correctly.  Your `printData` method only cares about updating the `TableModel`...IMHO

Comment: I still don't understand it at a very low level. If the `printData` method works correctly, that means my JTable contains the correct information, and the JTable is added to the `outputPanel`. I am just stuck here, can't understand what went wrong with the code....

Comment: But you created a new instance of `JPanel` and assigned it to `outputPanel` meaning that it was no longer point to the `JPanel` that was on the screen...

Comment: I think I don't fully understand how the event is being handled. After going through your suggestion above, I put in the exact code in the `buildOutputPanel` and `printData`. `printData` is only for input data into table, and `buildOutputPanel` adds the JTable. Since `buildOutputPanel` was called before `printData` in the constructor, how does it handle the new data from `printData`? Do I need to refresh it? When I click on `printData`, my IDE just gives me error.

Comment: `printData` supplies a new model to the `JTable`.  Swing uses a varient of the [Model-View-Controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller).  This means that the data is managed separately from the view.  So you could supply many different models to the single instance of `JTable` and each time, it would be updated

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for @MadProgrammer 's help! His reply helps me to fix many problems I have, and really tried to explain things to me. After consulting with my instructor, I have successfully compile and run my program by editing the `printData` method.

```
private void printData() 
    {
        DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(columnNames,name.size());
        resultTable.setModel(model);  
        for(int i=0; i<name.size(); i++)
        {
            resultTable.setValueAt(name.get(i),i,0);
            resultTable.setValueAt(department.get(i),i,1);
            resultTable.setValueAt(salary.get(i),i,2);
        }
    }
```